# It's taking one hour to upload 60MB document in Sharepoint using Java. How can I find the cause for delay?

Tags: java, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-online, msdn

We've a requirement to upload 100MB document in to Sharepoint. I've found an article where they are uploading using chunks with startUpload, continueUpload and finishUpload methods. I've tried using so, but it's taking 60 mins to upload the document. Is it the right code?

```
public Map<String, String> uploadFile(String folder, String fileName,
            byte[] binary, boolean overwrite,boolean toaddInsideFolder,String localFileURL) throws LoginException, IOException, URISyntaxException {            
        String url=URIUtil.encodePath("/Files/Add(url='" + fileName + "', overwrite=" + overwrite + ")");
        if(toaddInsideFolder)
            url = restServiceURL.toString() + "/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folder + "')"+url;
        else
            url = restServiceURL.toString() + "/Folders/GetByUrl('" + folder + "')"+url;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        //To receive xml response add below header to http get request
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
            httppost.addHeader("Cookie", getSecurityToken().getAuthCookiesToken());    
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String statusLine = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        String jsonresponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);
        String gUid =json.getJSONObject("d").getString("UniqueId");         
        String endpointUrlS = restServiceURL.toString() + "/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('"+ folder +"/"+fileName+"')/savebinarystream";
        HttpPost httppos = new HttpPost(url);
        //To receive xml response add below header to http get request
        httppos.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        httppos.addHeader("Cookie", getSecurityToken().getAuthCookiesToken());
        HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppos);           
        File file = new File(localFileURL);int fileSize=(int) file.length();
        final int chunkSize = 50 * 200 * 200;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) fileSize <= chunkSize ? (int) fileSize : chunkSize];    
        long count = 0;
        if (fileSize % chunkSize == 0)
            count = fileSize / chunkSize;
        else
            count = (fileSize / chunkSize) + 1;
        // try-with-resources to ensure closing stream
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
            int bytesAmount = 0;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i = 0;
            String startUploadUrl = "";
            int k = 0;
            while ((bytesAmount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAmount);
                byte partialData[] = baos.toByteArray();
                if (i == 0) {
                    startUploadUrl = restServiceURL.toString() + "/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('"+ folder +"/"+fileName+"')/StartUpload(uploadId=guid'"+gUid+"')";                       
                    executeMultiPartRequest(startUploadUrl, partialData);
                    System.out.println("first worked");
                    // StartUpload call
                } else if (i == count-1) {
                    String finishUploadUrl = restServiceURL.toString() + "/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('"+ folder +"/"+fileName+"')/FinishUpload(uploadId=guid'"+gUid+"',fileOffset="+i+")";
                    executeMultiPartRequest(finishUploadUrl, partialData);
                    System.out.println("FinishUpload worked");
                    // FinishUpload call
                } else {
                    String continueUploadUrl = restServiceURL.toString() + "/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('"+ folder +"/"+fileName+"')/ContinueUpload(uploadId=guid'"+gUid+"',fileOffset="+i+")";
                    executeMultiPartRequest(continueUploadUrl, partialData);
                    System.out.println("continue worked");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }           
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        return result;
    }
    public void executeMultiPartRequest(String urlString, byte[] fileByteArray) throws IOException, LoginException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");httppost.addHeader("Cookie", getSecurityToken().getAuthCookiesToken());
            HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(fileByteArray);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }
```

Comment: At a glance, this code looks appropriate. Can you add timing logs to this code to gain more insight. (It might help to test with smaller files—still big enough for multipart upload—that are still unexpectedly slow). Can you share timing information?
Are the chunk sizes appropriate, looks like 2MB. I'm not familiar with sharepoint's limits.

Comment: @mcint If I keep chunksize to 10MB also,time to upload the entire 60 MB file is 1 hour .Code hangs for sometime at httpclient.execute() in executeMultiPartRequest().

Comment: I’m surprised by the slow upload speed on each connection, which is worth following up on. However, it looks like you could get some more speed by having each chunk upload in parallel. `httpclient.execute(…)` is synchronous, right? So the chunk uploads will happen sequentially, not in parallel.

Comment: Can you confirm a different client can upload faster?

Comment: It could be a network limitation on your network, in transit, or coincident with high load on their end. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193962/ or http://www.jrjlee.com/2011/07/very-slow-upload-speeds-to-sharepoint.html. See if you can double check Limousine some other way. Another multipart upload app would provide a good comparison and sanity check. Minio might have azure libraries

Comment: Thanks for responding @mcint.My internet upload speed is a bit low.I've connected to high speed internet.But,If I can upload 60MB file in sharepoint online site in 3 mins,it's taking 16 mins to upload through attached code using chunks.Chunk upload is synchronous,not in parallel.Can you please let me know how to do chunk upload in parallel?

Comment: Concurrent/multithreaded programming is a while extra topic, worthy of questions and answers by itself. To start, the `java.util.concurrecy` package (or its successors) will be of help. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html
Essentially, you break up the work into separate chunks, each chunk knows which part of the file it needs to read and upload, the proper URL its part of multipart upload. After everything is uploaded there's a re-assemble parts request to complete it, which you're already using.

Comment: You might draw inspiration from AWS's library. It might be compatible with Azure, but I would bet against it 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-uploads-for-speed-and-reliability/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html